# Why can't access class variable when using __new__?

Tags: python, singleton

I have class as following

```
class Singleton:
    _instance = None
    class_variable = {'a': 1}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is not None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

when I create instance and access class_variable

```
inst_1 = Singleton()
print(inst_1.class_variable)
```

It shows an error

```
     11 inst_1 = Singleton()
---> 12 print(inst_1.class_variable)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_variable'
```

I don't know why?

Comment: Just look at your branch, the problem is very clear

Comment: @SergeyA Can you explain for me?

Comment: the `__new__` method returns `None`

Comment: remove `not` from `cls._instance is not None`

Comment: Peter, just go through the branch and substitute possible values for `_instance` and see which branch is taken. I firmly believe it would do you more good than spoonfeeding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`_instance` starts out `None`. But you only create an actual instance when `_instance` is *not* `None`, so you never actually call `super().__new__`.

Just change the test:

```
    if cls._instance is None:
```